# ng-repeat on Angular does not server the elements fast enough

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I am trying to use the [MixItUp](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com/learn/tutorial/get-started/) plugin for a portofolio, up to this point everything works fine:

```
<div id="Container" class="container" ng-controller="PortofolioController">
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="1"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="2"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="3"></div>
  <div class="mix category-2" data-myorder="4"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="5"></div>
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="6"></div>
  <div class="mix category-2" data-myorder="7"></div>
  <div class="mix category-2" data-myorder="8"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
</div>
```

But I want the elements of the `Container` to dynamically gathered from the controller and placed in the portofolio, so I tried:

```
<div id="Container" class="container" ng-controller="PortofolioController">
<div ng-repeat="element in portofolio.elements">
  <div class="mix category-1" data-myorder="1">{{element.something}}</div>
</div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
</div>
```

But nothing appears and the MixItUp plugin does not work, I cannot understand what conflict exist between them. Any help why this is happening?

**Update:**

when the code executed the class of the element change and there is a `ng-binding`.

```
<div class="mix category-1 ng-binding" data-myorder="0" data-orig-pos-x="15" data-orig-pos-y="78" style="-webkit-transition: none; transition: none;">Hydrogen</div>
```

Which I suppose is the problem because MixItUp uses the name of the classes. Is there any way to remove that?

Comment: If mixitUp does nothing else than sort your content, you could as well do that with ng-repeat and/or angular-filters.

Comment: @Charminbear no its not only sorting, I know that angular has this ability. It does some nice animations.